# Eclipse cross platform on USB with settings

Tags: eclipse, windows, macos, ide, cross-platform

I like to carry my IDE with me because I develope on multiple places. So currently I'm having my eclipse on a external hard drive with portable Java. All works great, because Eclipse is portable by default.

Since I have to work under Mac OS X I have to make Eclipse also working under it. I not only want to share my plugins, I also want to share all my settings from the windows installation with the Mac OS X installation. So for example if I would change a preference, it should also change it for my Mac OS X installation.

My first idea was to look at the file directory of both programs, and if they are similar I could only put the Mac OS X app inside it and all other dependent files will be shared with windows because it would be in the same directory. But the problem of this solution is that the file directory is not similar. As you can see here, the .ini is in another directory for example:

Mac OSX:
[image: Mac OS X eclipse]

Windows:[image: Windows eclipse]

So how can I share my eclipse plugins and whole settings with a Mac OS X installation?

Comment: Eclipse has several binaries and plugins which are specific to Macs or Windows or Linux so you have to have a separate install for each. Nearly all the preferences are stored in the workspace not the install directory.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that only the view of the windows and the plugins will be there, but not the settings of the preferences!?

Comment: Most preferences are in the workspace .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings directory in xxx.prefs files. Some in other .metadata/.plugins directories. A very small number of preferences are in the install 'configurations/.settings' directory.

Comment: Ok, how can I share **all settings** with no smears?